# Spock Prime's death date: ambiguity between his life span and his date of death in the alternate time line

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Early in *Star Trek Beyond*, the Enterprise lands at Yorktown Station, for shore leave.  On the Station, two Vulcans tell Spock that Spock Prime has died.  Spock looks at a sheet that has a picture of Spock Prime and lettering underneath that I thought were birth and death dates, but the scene was so fleeting that I am not sure of this.

Was the lettering birth and death dates?  Or something else?  And, if birth and death dates, what was the death date?  If the death date was the date in the alternate time line when Spock Prime died, he would seem much younger -- by decades -- than his actual life span.  If the death date reflected his actual life span it would be in the future of the alternate time line. How is this ambiguity resolved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you've not gone boss-eyed. His birth and death-dates are actually [pretty confusing](https://youtu.be/x8w95xIdH4o?t=26s).

[image]

Spock was born in 2230 in the prime timeline. He lived until [2387](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2387) *within the prime timeline* and then traveled back in time to [2258](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2258) where he lived until his death in 2263 *within the new reboot timeline*.

He therefore died at the *chronological* age of 162. Had he not traveled in time (but had still lived the same number of years) his date of death would be **2392.**

Comment: boo i was just hitting submit

Comment: @Himarm - Gotta catch em' all.